# RequireJS does not follow relative path for data-main with baseUrl set

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Using requireJS, I am trying to specify a path for my data-main that is different from the baseUrl. It seems that requireJS is ignoring whatever I type before the file name, and always look for the file in the baseUrl folder.

I have the following folder structure :

```
index.html
scripts/
  lib/
    require.js
  test/
    main2.js
  config.js
```

Contents of index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script data-main="test/main2" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

Contents of config.js :

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts"
});
```

And I am getting a 404 error for : GET [...]/scripts/main2.js , even though it should be looking for [...]/scripts/test/main2.js. If I remove the config.js file and use data-main="scripts/test/main2" it works, but I would like to be able to specify a baseUrl for my project.

Any ideas ?

Edit : following the answer by Waxen :

- Even if I use "scripts/test/main2", "/scripts/test/main2", or "whateverIWant/main2" in my data-main, it oddly always looks for "scripts/main2.js"

Note that I am using requirejs 2.1.8

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit - it was misleading to see the code from the accepted answer in your question. The fact that you have accepted an answer is enough to tell other users what the solution to the problem in your question, is!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't working how you want it to because you're calling require with a data-main before you're setting the baseURL.  I'm not sure why it's trying to go to scripts/main2.js though; I would expect it to attempt to load test/main2.js rather than scripts/main2.js.  However, that's beside the point.

What you need to do is make sure that your baseURL is available to require before it tries to load you data-main.  This can be accomplished by including your config first and using the syntax from the second example here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config.

---

Contents of index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
        <script data-main="test/main2" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

Contents of config.js :

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "scripts"
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tested your method that does not rely on the data-main attribute, and it does work. However, if I give the full path in data-main ("scripts/test/main2" or "/scripts/test/main2") I still get a 404 error saying it could not find scripts/main2.js, which does not match the path I give. I am using requirejs 2.1.8. I would prefer the data-main method so I can use the same config file for the main application and the unit tests.

Comment: You're right, that first one didn't work.  I ran a couple tests locally and updated my answer to remove the first option, and updated the remaining solution to use data-main.

Comment: Including the configuration before the require.js file as stated in the documentation did the trick indeed, thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

I read this thread and couldn't quite understand why using the data-main attribute to point to a configuration js file wouldn't be the same as specifying the configuration before loading Require, as the answer to this thread suggests.

In my experiments, I learned that setting values using a data-main config js file *might* work (then, again, it might not). To those new to Require and AMDs and asynchronisity in general, the "might work" notion has to do with the fact that asynchronous operations run when then can--and not in any predictable order.

Having established that, there is a very important point made in the current version of the RequireJS documentation that eluded me until now:

> You may also call require.config from your data-main Entry Point, but
>   be aware that the data-main script is loaded asynchronously. Avoid
>   other entry point scripts which wrongly assume that data-main and its
>   require.config will always execute prior to their script loading.

For further information, see: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main

Being new to RequireJS, I was mildly appalled to learn this--and I wasted a lot of time trying to debug path-access problems. At this stage it is unclear to me why anyone would use data-main (especially to define a baseUrl) since this reference will only randomly work. Instead the solution suggested by this thread (in which you set the baseUrl in a script tag that is NOT asynchronous, will work as expected and will reliably set the RequireJS configuration before kicking-off RequireJS.

Comment: its funny you say "mildly appalled", it actually pisses me off... whats the point of requirejs then, if requirejs itself cant even guarantee that its configuration has been loaded? imo, this is a serious deficiency.  The answer then, isn't the obtuse "just require['scripts/config'] before all your code" but to add a new function, "required" or "requiredWithConfig" that would wait until configuration actually loads, and potentially doesnt run at all if config fails to load, which is better than random javascript errors of unable to load things that configuration would've loaded correctly.