# RequireJS sporadic 404's

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am getting the following script loading error sporadically (like 1 out of 20 times):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I have read the various other posts here, but I don't immediately see which problem I am guilty of.  Here is my setup:

I have a single script tag with a `data-main` which loads the file `common.js`.  This is common to several pages:

```
<script data-main="path/to/common.js" src="path/to/require.js"></script>
```

`common.js` is where I load all of my common project dendencies via `require.config({...`

Then, in an individual page in order to load page specific scripts, I do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   require(['common'], function() {
     require(['/path/to/myScript']);
   });
</script>
```

`myScript` depends on `common` being loaded.

Despite the data-main being loaded with 'async' doesn't the 'common' dependency in my outer require definition *force* common to be loaded prior to 'myScript'?

Comment: Your question title is spot on. I'm so frustrated with RequireJs right now. This other answer and first comment below it summarize how angry I am about how nonsensical RequireJs is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24182533/470749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data-main file should be the only entry point into your scripts. Since the data-main file is loaded asynchronously, your script-tag script is not entirely guaranteed to run after the data-main file is loaded.

If you simply cannot make data-main your only entry point, I would define a function above where you load require.js, which is executed at the end of your data-main file.

```
<script>
// unfortunately global
window.initializer = function() {
  require(['/path/to/myScript']);
}
</script>

<script data-main="path/to/common.js" src="path/to/require.js"></script>
```

And then in your data-main file:

```
require.config = {
  // ...
}

initializer()
```

I would also consider renaming common.js to config.js because that's what the data-main file is supposed to be used for.

Comment: See official docs for better ways: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module